# Why the bone counts increse when I use Blender to export SMPL fbx?

Tags: blender, fbx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqCGa.png)
Is there any function translate SMPL fbx position? I try to use blender to modify, but when I export and import again, each hip and spine has one extra bone:***_end, I don't why. Even if I delete this bones and export, the problem happen again.

Can you help me find a function translate the SMPL position, or tell me why my blender raise this problem.